# $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)<0$ the there exists $x>0$ such that $g(x)<0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a function with a fact that $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)<0$. Then I need to show that $g(x)<0$ for some $x>0$.

Suppose $g(x)>0\quad \forall x>0$ then

$\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$= $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}<0$

and

$\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$=$\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}>0$.

Thus this is a contradiction to the fact that $g$ is derivable at $x=0$.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: From the fact that, say, $g(x)>0$ for all $x>0$ it only follows that the right derivative is non-negative. The limit of a positive function is not necessarily positive. Also, you seem to be assuming $g(x)>0$ also for $x<0$, which is not needed.

Comment: I suggest you use a local Taylor expansion to order $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Using your idea, from the fact that $g(x)\ge 0$ for $x>0$ it follows that the right derivative at zero is $\ge 0$, contradicting the fact that you know that $g'(0)<0$. What I do not like about this is that what this actually proves is that at some $x>0$ you have $g(x)<0$, which is true but actually $g(x)<0$ in some right neighborhood of $x=0$, a stronger conclusion.

Comment: i see..thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon=-\frac{g'(0)}{2}$ then exists $\delta>0$ such that $\frac{g(x)}{x} <\frac{g'(0)}{2}<0, \forall x\in (-\delta,\delta)$

Take $x_0=\frac{\delta}{2}$ and you have the conlusion